# JobService not starting after every minute

Tags: java, android, service, android-jobscheduler

### MyActivity.java

```
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(jobId,
            new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class))
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();
    JobScheduler scheduler =
            (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int s = scheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

### MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends JobService{
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.v("SUCCESS", "Job started!");
    jobFinished(params, true);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
```

I was trying to create a jobService that runs after every minute but if I put 1 in the method  .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)), it does not seems to work however if i put 15 in it it seems to work fine. can anyone tell me how i can kick off myservice after every minute with Jobservice ?

Answer (score 1):

Minimum interval for `JobScheduler` is 15 mins that's why 1 min interval is not working and 15 min is working